# The PHP code gets empty string from JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't get the string from the JS code to the PHP code

here is the code, which initializes when I push enter in a text input:

```
$('#user').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {

  var val = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: ({'latt':val
            })
        });


<?php

$val = $_POST['latt'];

echo "alert('$val')";

?>

    }
});
```

where #user is the id of this text input

When I run the code, I see the alert that shows nothing

Before I exactly know that the JS val is not empty

Thank you in advance

P.S. my page is index.php

Comment: How do you expect to echo an `alert()` after the page has been sent from the server to the client. You really need to read up on Ajax, and how it works, and you'll understand that once the code has left the server, you can't change it with serverside scripting, but you can send something back with ajax and then do the alert on the client side.

Comment: Yes, but it is that moment when I don't understand why it worked in another script. I used the same one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP code runs *before* the page is sent to the browser. That PHP block will simply echo the value of `$_POST['latt']` as it stood when you navigated to the page. You need to access the response from the server in the success callback:

```
$('#user').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {

        var val = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: {
                'latt': val
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: now it shows that it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping the object in parentheses (see the `data: ()` line). Remove the parentheses, and your code should function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: { 'latt': val }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously at first page load it will give you blank alert as event has not yet occured so no value has been sent via ajax and the echo part is in page execution without any conditions.

But when actual event occurs it will return the whole index.php page as response , so their is no way the actual alert thing will occur again. So i would suggest you to separate both javascript and php part so that client-server request-response will occur perfectly.

Comment: I tried to separate them, but it didn't help at all